# Angular Component automatically scrolls to middle when opened as MAT_DIALOG

Tags: angular, typescript, scroll, mat-dialog

I have an angular website, where pages can be opened under specific routes, but I also can (by clicking on specific buttons) open these pages as dialog. When I open these pages as dialogs, the dialog automatically starts at the middle/bottom of the page, although I want to start at the top.
I have one component for the page, and one component for the page dialog, that opens this page as dialog. The dialog page is opened when the user clicks on a button

I have tried these things, but they did not work:
`window.scroll(0, 0)` on ngOnInit and AfterViewInit
`this.scroll.nativeElement.scrollTop = 0;` on ngOnInit and AfterViewInit
I also have this in my app-routing.module.ts: `imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'})]`

Comment: Please add enough code to reproduce the problem. In case you have a tabbable element in your component, this is expected behavior. As per [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview): "Once a dialog opens, the dialog will automatically focus the first tabbable element." In the docs they also explain how to change this behavior.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.